# Rails: Collection select in simple form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I am using simple form gem and I am wondering how do you do a collection_select ? I know you can do a select, but how do you get the values from a collection?

So, for example, how would you do this in a simple form:

```
collection_select(:post, :author_id, Author.all, :id, :name_with_initial, :prompt => true)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would do it like this:

```
collection_select(:post, :author, Author.all, :id, :name_with_initial)
```

Take a look at [SimpleForm - Collection Select Input](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/master/lib/simple_form/inputs/collection_select_input.rb)

Comment: This is incorrect. Please adjust your code to: `collection_select(:post, :author, Author.all, :id, :name_with_initial)`